# Iterate through all combinations of hash keys in Perl

Tags: perl, hash, key

I would like to identify clients with similar consumption choice, and have the following purchase data that lists the clients who bought various products:

```
$product1 = qw/client1 client2 client3 client4/;
$product2 = qw/client2 client4/;
$product3 = qw/client3 client4/;
$product4 = qw/client1 client5/;
$product5 = qw/client1/;
```

I thought that creating a hash with products as key and clients as value might be a good idea.

```
%Purchase;
$Purchase{$product} = @clients;
```

Now I need to compare all possible combinations of products to see if there are some overlapping clients:

```
    my @overlapped12 = intersect($Purchase{$product1}, $Purchase{$product2}); # 2 products 
    my @overlapped13 = intersect($Purchase{$product1}, $Purchase{$product3}); # 2 products 
    [...]
    my @overlapped123 = intersect($Purchase{$product1}, $Purchase{$product2}, $Purchase{$product3); # 3 products
[...]
my @overlapped12345 = intersect($Purchase{$product1},$Purchase{$product2},$Purchase{$product3},$Purchase{$product4},$Purchase{$product5});
```

Given that I have dozens of products to check for dozens of clients, this iteration becomes very inefficient and terribly slow. Could you please help me improve this computation?

Thank you

Comment: I'm quite sure that `$Purchase{$product} = @clients;` doesn't do what you expected.

Comment: It is impossible to assign a list `qw/client1 client2 client3/` to a scalar `$product`. You must either assign a scalar value, such as a reference `[ qw/ ... / ]` or use an array `@product`.

Comment: As the two last comments would imply, you should never, ever post approximate code, or code you made up on the spot to "describe" your problem. Always use real code that is the same code you are having problems with.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Data::Powerset](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Data-PowerSet/) to generate all the subsets of the products and iterate through them. It would look something like this (untested)

```
use Data::PowerSet 'powerset';

my %Purchase;
my %overlapped;  

for my $set ( powerset keys %Purchase ) {
    push $overlapped{ join(", ", @$set) }, intersect( @Purchase{ @$set } );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think rather than having products as keys, you should create hash with clients as keys like this:

```
Clients = {
    Client1 => [product1, product2, product3, ...]
    Client2 => [product1, product2]
    Client3 => [product1, product2, product3, product4]
    Client4 => [product1]
    ...
}
```

This way you can easily check if a client has more than one product in it's list.

Now what you can do to achieve this is,

1. `split` the product string and push the clients in list
2. and for every product string `append` clients to this list by spliting
3. Then get a unique values list from this list by using `uniq` function from

`use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);`

or directly create hash with client keys as you get and check next time if key exists

Add products to each client as you find, this you can do by checking if key exists.